# img src attribute returns the url of the page when blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After setting the `src` attribute of an `<img>` to an empty string with `jQuery`, the `src` returns the current url of the page when I look it up again.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z5f0vp20/1/) *(Notice the alert text is the url of the page)*

Is this normal? How can I check if the `src` is empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check for the attribute value, the property returns a relative value if an absolute path is not specified.

```
$("#testImage").attr("src")
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bf5z32rv/)

Comment: Weird...I thought that `prop` replaced `attr` but I guess `attr` is still the correct method to use sometimes.

Comment: In any case, this fixes it and I will accept asap. Thank you!

Comment: @jlars62 both `.prop` and `attr` are still there, both has different use cases

Comment: it's not a normal behaviour to get one value through .src and another through .getAttribute("src") ...

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old post. but i would like to share my solution.

use below code to get image src.

```
document.getElementById("img1").getAttribute("src")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect element on your fiddle, you'll see it's actually giving this.

```
<img id="testImage" src="">
```

So why are you getting the current url when you pass it through alert? Think of it this way. If your page is one/two/three/page.html, and you set the src to "image.jpg", the path to the image will effectively be one/two/three/image.jpg. In that same case, if you set the src to "", the path would then be the same, but without image.jpg. The path would be one/two/three. So yes, I believe it's normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

add some cache tricks, of course using jQuery:

```
<img src='somepicture.jpg&nocache=1898333' /> 
 <img src='nopicture.jpg&nocache=1298912' />
```

by setting no value to the src attribute it will point to the root website, and yes, that's normal.